# Code Igniter is not sending email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm using Code Igniter, but when I try to send an email it is not working. I have the following code:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from("ask@server.pk");

$this->email->to('something@gmail.com');

$this->email->subject('Corporate Client Mail');

$this->email->message('test email');

$this->email->send();
```

What could cause this script to not send email? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Which preferences to you have in your config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably forgot to configure the mail server you want to use.
If you test this on a local test server you probably don't have any mail server installed which is required to send emails. What you can do is use gmail SMTP server to send out the emails. You do this like this:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'sender_mailid@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype'  => 'text'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```